# Requisição POST

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, http

Saudações,

possuo um servidor em python de teste:

```
from flask import request, Flask

app = Flask (__name__)

@app.route ('/Teste', methods=['POST'])
def teste():
 recebido = request.form['variavel'] 
 print(recebido)
 return 'OK'
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run ()
```

Em python também eu posso, como teste, realizar um POST para verificar se está funcionando o servidor:

```
import requests
requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/Teste", data={'variavel': 'TUDOOK'})
```

Não tenho nenhuma familiaridade com C++ senão para leitura e implementar coisas simples, estou mexendo em uma engine de um jogo antigo e consegui fazer uma opção de acessar um site (que por padrão é método GET). Como eu faço para enviar um requisição POST tão simples como no python acima? No caso, não me interessa a resposta do servidor, desejo apenas enviar a variável e encerrar, como no exemplo acima.

OBS: Vi algumas postagens utilizando o CURL, neste caso seria só com uma linha também utilizando-o? Ou seria mais prático um exemplo como esse: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html sem a resposta? Se sim, o que seria o CURL *curl; (como o ponteiro funciona neste caso)?